# GRUB4DOS error dual boot Kali Linux 2016.2 and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, kali-linux, grub2, grub4dos

I was trying to install Kali Linux 2016.2 dual boot on a Windows 10 laptop, but every time I failed with `GRUB4DOS Error`. I raised this question a month ago and I found the solution after 2-3 days of trial and error. I forgot to answer then, but now I have edited the question and I have provided the answered below.

[image]
<sup>**GRUB4DOS error screen**</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fallow the steps carefully
i'll define the main steps if you want to know more deep like how to create partition n all step by step please google for it most-likely you'll get a precise video for that.

1. Create 50 GB to 60 GB of **`Unallocated Space`** by shrinking volume of any of your partition from **`Disk Management`** on your windows PC
2. > Using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) for making kali-linux bootable pendrive
   >
   > - `Partition scheme : MBR for BIOS/UEFI`
   > - `File system : FAT 32`
3. > Kali partitions define manually (Best For General Users)
   >   `#7    20GB   /`
   >   `#8    2GB    /boot`
   >   `#9    4GB    /swap`
   >   `#10   700MB  /temp`
   >   `#11   4GB    /var`
   >   `#12   25GB   /home`
4. > *`/dev/sda8`* Partition name for boot loader installation this is partition i which i created above for /boot for every PC name may differ according to the partition scheme
5. > Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) Tool from NeoSmart website
   >   for adding new operating system entry into the boot menu
   >
   > 1. click on `Add New Entry`
   > 2. click on `Linux/BSD`
   > 3. Type: `SysLinux`
   >      Name: `Kali Linux` *(What ever name you want to give)*
   >      Drive: `Partition 8 (Linux-2GiB)` (Choose the partition which you created for /boot)
6. Finally click on `Add Entry`
   You have successfully installed and added KaliLinux into the boot menu

**Note**

- Please fallow the steps carefully and do not make changes to the **`Boot Menu`** or any other option in the **`EsayBCD Tool`** except what is defined above or it can cause OS booting problems.
- I would suggest to take backup of your **`Boot Menu Configuration`** on an external drive by clicking on **`BCD Bckup/Repair`**.
- You can choose to install **`Kali's Boot Loader`** into **`Master Boot Partition Of Windows`** then you do not require **`EasyBCD`**, which i do not prefer personally because if you do that **`Kali's Boot Menu`** loads before the **`Window's Boot Menu`** and  makes **`Kali Linux default`** operating system where you can choose to load windows but it can cause errors or system failure while updating your windows OS.
- You can create the partitions according to your requirement what i defined above was my preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Also i found another way and 100% working. Download boot-repair-disk from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ and burn it. After boot from your removable disk and there is an option for repair grub. One click, wait, finish! Reboot machine and you have the grub fixed.