# Pc can not find grub after windows 10 recent update, but I can not find it manually too

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

This is a common error when you use dual boot and you upgrade windows. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10. The error I came across is:

> error: no such partition Entering rescue mode...

I found online The basic solution. Which is to find manually where the grub is. So using the command ls it lists all the partitions.

Then using the command ls (name of partition) I tried to found out where the grub is, but every time I got the message that the Filesystem is unknown. So basically I could not find it. I tried to set grub's path every time to a different partition, but when I use insmod normal command, I got again the error: unknown filesystem for every partition that i used as grub's path.

Any idea how to fix that? Could it be that there are some partitions that I can not see?

Comment: Use boot-repair in Linux live media. [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: Did not work. @Biswa

Answer (score 0):

**Method1**

1.Enter Windows recovery mode by pressing "**esc**"(may be different way on your computer) while booting.

2.Click on "**Troubleshoot**"

3.Click "**Advanced options**"

4.Choose "**Command Prompt**"

5.Type the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

6.Now restart your computer

***Good if this works for you, if not then try***

**Method2.**

1.Use Rufus to make Ubuntu live USB drive and boot into Ubuntu.

2.Start terminal type

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

3.Note down the root partion of linux installation.
 Example: **(/dev/sda8)** in my case.
and your boot partion which is indicated by `*`
sign.
 Example : **(/dev/sda6)** in my case.

4.Now mount your root partion to make some changes and some binding.
Below replace "**/dev/sda8**" with your root partion.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /pro /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

5.Now change the root directory from usb drive to the hardrive's root directory

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

6.Now install the grub to the boot partion of your's, which you noted down with the `*` sign
replace "**/dev/sda6**" with your boot partion.

```
grub-install /dev/sda6
```

7.Now type.

```
exit
```

8.Unmount partation previously mounted earlier.

```
sudo unmount /mnt/dev
sudo unmount /mnt/proc
sudo unmount /mnt/sys
sudo unmount /mnt
```

9.Remove the pendrive and reboot your pc.

Comment: @Antonis Koutou if it helped you can upvote the answer

Comment: Suggestion : Never make changes to  windows boot partion "MBR" Master Boot Record while dual boot, instead install linux boot to a seperate partion and use third-party tools like EasyBCD to add linux boot to the windows boot menu.

Comment: Next time you can refer to this post while dual booting windows and linux https://superuser.com/a/1183848/691100

Answer (score -1):

Ok, what I did and worked was to boot Windows from usb. And then go to troubleshooting then open the command prompt and enter this command: 
Bootrec /fixmrb. But now I can not enter Ubuntu anymore. Anyways! I am fine.